# Pygame problems: The sprite won't move when key pressed. And yes, I looked around on SO

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

So I'm back at it with making a game again and I'm using Pygame.

However, I need to move the player sprite. And it just won't cooperate.

How it's meant to work is that when an arrow key is pressed, it should move the sprite in that corresponding arrow's direction. obvious enough haha.

But it didn't. And there's no traceback as well.

So I turn to my good friend, Stack Overflow.
I tried out some answers but they just don't work for me. Or the mechanic of the game and the direction I'm taking it (pun not intended)

So, anyone have any idea how to fix it?
Here's the code. Full thing on GitHub (just in case): https://github.com/E-Lee-Za/Eleeza-Crafter-The-Game

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
#INITIALISE THE WINDOW.
#CONSTANTS ARE CAPITAL, VARIABLES ARE LOWERCASE
SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
SCREENSIZE = [SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)
BG_COL = [255, 123, 67]
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(BG_COL)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = pygame.image.load("Sprites/player.png")
        self.x = 445
        self.y = 550

#make functions        
def handle_keys():
    """ Handles Keys """
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dist = 5 
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
        player.y += dist # move down
    elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
        player.y -= dist # move up
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
        player.x += dist # move right
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
        player.x -= dist # move left

#MAIN GAME LOOP (WHERE WE PUT ALL THE FUNCTIONS TOGETHER)
running = True
while running:   
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            running = False

    #UNNECESSARY STUFF

    player = Player()
    #IF KEY PRESSED
    #MOVE PLAYER SPRITE
    screen.blit(player.sprite, (player.x, player.y))
    handle_keys()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you verified that the underlying `(x,y)` coordinates are changing? Maybe printing to the console after a key press?

Comment: @IanQuah Hmm...lemme try that...they don't seem to be changing...?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can copy, paste and run to test? Having said that, it looks like it's just not getting caught so perhaps print `key` to see what the value is

Comment: @IanQuah I already heavily modified my original code to produce the same results, but I'll see what I can do...well, there's no way for me to simplify it any more...the allegedly MCVE version is already in the question. sorry.

Comment: @IanQuah Something strange: I tried printing out `key` and it prints out a very l o n g list of `0`s. I wonder what that is.

Comment: The long list of `0s` represents possible key presses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184560/discussion-between-eleeza-and-ian-quah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I had to debug it for you

1) `player = Player()` should be OUTSIDE the while loop. In this case, it's getting reinitialized constantly

2) `player` should be passed into `handle_keys`

---

I'm making the assumption that you're a newbie so I'm going to layout the thought process I had and how I debugged it since I think that will be more useful for you in the future:

1) put a print statement in each condition like so

```
if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
    print('Down')
    player.y += dist # move down
elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
    print('Up')
    player.y -= dist # move up
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
    print('Right')
    player.x += dist # move right
elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
    print('left')
    player.x -= dist # move left
```

which all printed correctly - this means that your `handle_keys` is kind of working

2) print out the `(x,y)` coordinates of player immediately AFTER `handle_keys` which is when I noticed that the `(x,y)` values seemed to always be getting reset. This was indicative to me that either

- the player instance was never actually getting changed
- the player instance was always getting reinitialized

I'll leave you to figure out what code changes you need to make to solve your issue

Comment: The image moves now, but it keeps copying itself.

Comment: That's a separate question - I have no experience with pygame so I probably can't help you there

Comment: Sweet! Good initiative :) Happy programming and hope the game goes well! If the answer above helped you solve your problem please mark it as the accepted answer